# Adding a link to Facebook using the AddThis "Share" link not always showing the picture

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, addthis

Using the "Share" link of a page does not always show the picture of the page as thumbnail in the Facebook link. For example, linking the page http://www.tekes.fi/tekes/tulokset-ja-vaikutukset/caset/2013/managed-outcomes-tuotantotalouden-logiikkaa-terveyspalveluihin/ to Facebook by using the red "Share" > "Facebook" link at the bottom of the page makes the link show in Facebook so that the picture of the article also shows in the link. However, linking the page http://www.tekes.fi/nyt/blogit-2013/katoavatko-tyopaikat/ in the same way does not show the picture in the Facebook link. The "Share" links in the pages are implemented by using the AddThis Toolbox.

When copying the urls of the above links directly to Facebook, both of the links are shown with pictures in Facebook as they should.

Could you tell us what could cause the problem with the "Share" link? Is there something wrong with the "Share" link implementation? Is there a solution to this problem? We have tried to add a

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<picture url>" />
```

tag to the pages with no effect. The Facebook debugger tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) tells about both of the pages the same things: that the 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags, and that the provided og:image is not big enough and that an other image will be used instead.

Here are some other urls where the picture shows correctly when sharing it to Facebook using the "Share" link:

- http://www.tekes.fi/nyt/uutiset-2013/suomen-peliteollisuus-nousi-kahteen-miljardiin/
- http://www.tekes.fi/nyt/uutiset-2013/suomalaisyritys-pistaa-kampoihin-pelikonsolijateille/
- http://www.tekes.fi/nyt/uutiset-2013/verkosta-vauhtia-liiketoimintaan-ict-ammattilaisten-avulla/

Here are some other urls where the picture does not show correctly when sharing it to Facebook using the "Share" link:

- http://www.tekes.fi/nyt/uutiset-2013/yritys-suomen-puhelinpalvelu-tarjoaa-hyvan-kanavan-yrittajille/
- http://www.tekes.fi/tekes/tulokset-ja-vaikutukset/caset/2013/lasten-sijoitukset-vahenivat-raisiossa/

Answer (score -1):

The magic begins with using `<figure>` tag around article image. In this case, sharing works better. For example in Facebook and Google+.

Comment: Yes. Besides Open Graph just try FIGURE tag. Facebook in most cases take pictures from inside FIGURE tag, and in most cases this picture showing in full width inside fasebook post (in opposite to images got from plain image tag).